# How do i build react-native application avoiding the many breaking changes that lead to failure?

Tags: react-native

i just created a new react-native app using npx create-react-native-app myapp which was successfully created. but when i try to build it using gradlew assembleRelease, i get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-30

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 43s
```

it appears like theres a gradle problem. how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the perfect way to build react native apps ive found is using the command `assembleRelease'. this builds your code and gives you an apk